# Count vowels in a list of strings and print the counts

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a code that must print only vowels from my strings in the array list but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right in my method.  How do I resolve this? Its only printing out 5 of them because I'm not sure how to directly get each specific vowels. Please find the below code that I have tried.

```
import java.util.*;

public class vowels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> vowels = new ArrayList<String>();

        vowels.add("mitsubishi");
        vowels.add("subaru");
        vowels.add("nissan");
        vowels.add("honda");
        vowels.add("toyota");


        averageVowels(vowels);
    }

    public static void averageVowels(ArrayList<String> vowels) {

        System.out.println(vowels);

        int number = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.size(); i++)
        {
            if (vowels.get(i).contains("a") || vowels.get(i).contains("e") || vowels.get(i).contains("i") ||vowels.get(i).contains("o") || vowels.get(i).contains("u"))
            {
                number++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("a count: " +number);
        System.out.println("e count: " +number);
        System.out.println("i count: " +number);
        System.out.println("o count: " +number);
        System.out.println("u count: " +number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: which textbook are you using ?

Comment: which one am i supposed to look at

Comment: Building Java Programs 3rd Edtion

Comment: Your program currently counts the number of words that contain any vowels at all, and then it prints that same number five times. If you want to count occurrences of each of the five possible vowels, then you need five different int variables to count them. If you want to hold off on learning regex, you can just loop through each word, checking each letter to see if it's a vowel. `for (char c : vowels.get(i).toCharArray())`

Comment: yeah its only printing out 5

Comment: Because there are five words and all five of them contain at least one vowel. Your five `println` calls are all referencing the same `number` variable, without it changing in between, so you shouldn't expect it to be different.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I dont understand what I have to write after the for (char c :vowels.get(i).toCharArray())

Answer (score 1):

You can do without any loops, quite easily so

```
public static void averageVowels(ArrayList<String> vowels) {
    System.out.println(vowels);
    String arrayToString = vowels.toString();
    int length = arrayToString.length();
    System.out.println("a count: " + (length - arrayToString.replace("a", "").length()));
    System.out.println("e count: " + (length - arrayToString.replace("e", "").length()));
    System.out.println("i count: " + (length - arrayToString.replace("i", "").length()));
    System.out.println("o count: " + (length - arrayToString.replace("o", "").length()));
    System.out.println("u count: " + (length - arrayToString.replace("u", "").length()));
}
```

It prints

```
[mitsubishi, subaru, nissan, honda, toyota]
a count: 4
e count: 0
i count: 4
o count: 3
u count: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 5 different variables to count the number of the vowel. For example numbera, number e etc. Then you will need 5 if statements (one for each vowel) each of which will increase its respective count by 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.size(); i++)
for (int j = 0; j<vowels.get(j).length(); j++) { 
if (vowels.get(i).charAt('a'))
    {
        numbera++;
    }
if (vowels.get(i).charAt('e'))
    {
        numbere++;
    }
if (vowels.get(i).charAt('i'))
    {
        numberi++;
    }   
if (vowels.get(i).charAt('o'))
    {
        numbero++;
    }  
if (vowels.get(i).charAt('u'))
    {
        numberu++;
    }}
```

Comment: so each then 5 different loops for each string?

Comment: No you can stick with the one loop if you wish but the loop needs an if statement for each individual vowel, if you dont understand i can edit my response to have a code sample.

Comment: Your current setup will also cause issues if the same vowel occurs twice in the same string and you need to count it twice

Answer (score 0):

You want to count five types of things, so you need five variables:

```
int aCount = 0;
int eCount = 0;
int iCount = 0;
int oCount = 0;
int uCount = 0;
```

There are many different ways you could loop through each of the words, and then each of the characters in each of the words. Here's one way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.size(); i++) {
    String lowerCaseWord = vowels.get(i).toLowerCase(); //get lowercase version so we don't have to check each letter twice

    for (int j=0; j<lowerCaseWord.length(); j++){  //loop through each char in the string
        char c = lowerCaseWord.charAt(j);
        if (c == 'a') aCount++;
        else if (c == 'e') eCount++;
        else if (c == 'i') iCount++;
        else if (c == 'o') oCount++;
        else if (c == 'u') uCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you get the output?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    if (vowels.get(i).contains("a") || vowels.get(i).contains("e") || vowels.get(i).contains("i") ||vowels.get(i).contains("o") || vowels.get(i).contains("u"))
```

only checks if the string contains a, e, i, o, or u. If it found one of these, it won't bother to check the rest of the string. And since you are using ||, in your if statement, it will not evaluate the next conditions if the current condition is already true, so it will proceed to increment number.
If you want to find the number of each vowel, One way is to loop through the string by turning it into a char array and check if a character is a vowel. Then you should create a counter for each vowel and a separated if/switch statement for each. For example with an if statement.

```
int aCount = 0;
int eCount = 0;
int iCount = 0;
int oCount = 0;
int uCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.size(); i++) {
    for (char c : vowels.get(i).toCharArray()) {
    if (c == 'a') {
        aCount++;
    } else if (c == 'e') {
        eCount++;
    } else (c == 'i') {
        iCount++;
    } else if (c == 'o') {
        oCount++;
    } else if (c == 'u') {
        uCount++;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation will be efficient. Maintaining a single char array of size 256 would be good enough, which works not only for vowels but for any ASCII character.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Vowels {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> vowels = new ArrayList<String>();

    vowels.add("mitsubishi");
    vowels.add("subaru");
    vowels.add("nissan");
    vowels.add("honda");
    vowels.add("toyota");


    averageVowels(vowels);
}

public static void averageVowels(ArrayList<String> vowels) {

    System.out.println(vowels);
    int[] chars = new int[256];
    int number = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.size(); i++)
    {
        for (char c : vowels.get(i).toCharArray()) {
            chars[c]++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("a count: " +chars['a']);
    System.out.println("e count: " +chars['e']);
    System.out.println("i count: " +chars['i']);
    System.out.println("o count: " +chars['o']);
    System.out.println("u count: " +chars['u']);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, but say now i want to just count all the vowels together as a whole, say there are 5 'a', 3 'e', 2 'i', 1 '0' and 4 'u' and i want just want the total vowels and the output to be "vowels: 15"

Comment: Just sum them up. Something like int sum = chars['a'] + chars['e'] + chars['i'] + chars['o'] + chars['u'];

Comment: The range of `char` is U+0000 to U+FFFD. (And, of ASCII: 0 to 127.)